# why does the first model runn but i have trouble with the second?

Tags: r, lme4

This is the code I ran for the models and beneath I left the error code from the second model as well as the dput() of the dataset. My assumption is that the NA values in the CRP_FU column are cuasing this issue to occur but im not entirely certain. i can also supply the output for the table showing the number of observations for each class.

```
 # LMM model RANDOM INTERCEPT & SLOPE (2-way interaction)
        
        # Simplify the random effects structure
        model_CRP <- lmer(
               COMP_MEM_FU ~ AB_binding * time_years_FU + GENDER + EDU_VERHAGE_YEARS + (1 | famnr)+ (1+time_years_FU | famnr:EMI),
               data = df_long_final,
               REML = TRUE,
               control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 50000))
        )
         
        summary(model_CRP)
        
        
        #LMM model 3WEGS INTERACTIE (RANDOM INTERCEPT & SLOPE)
        
        # Simplify the random effects structure
        model_CRP_3way <- lmer(
          COMP_MEM_FU ~ AB_binding * CRP_FU * time_years_FU + EDU_VERHAGE_YEARS + GENDER + 
          (1 | famnr)+ (1+time_years_FU| famnr:EMI),
          data = df_long_final,
          REML = TRUE,
          control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 50000))
        )
        
        summary(model_CRP_3way)
```

Runnning the first model is fine but runnning the second model gives me this error;

```
> Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: famnr:EMI)
```

Here is the dput:

```
> dput(head(df_long_final)) structure(list(AGE = c(70.9, 70.9, 70.9,
> 70.9, 70.9, 70.9), GENDER = c(0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0), EDU_VERHAGE_YEARS = c(13, 13, 13, 13, 17, 17), 
>     famnr = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AB_binding = c(0.116957518, 
>     0.116957518, 0.116957518, 0.116957518, 0.134414065, 0.134414065
>     ), EMI = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("EMI_301", 
>     "EMI_302", "EMI_303", "EMI_304", "EMI_305", "EMI_306", "EMI_307", 
>     "EMI_308", "EMI_309", "EMI_310", "EMI_311", "EMI_312", "EMI_313", 
>     "EMI_314", "EMI_315", "EMI_316", "EMI_317", "EMI_318", "EMI_319", 
>     "EMI_320", "EMI_321", "EMI_322", "EMI_325", "EMI_326", "EMI_327", 
>     "EMI_328", "EMI_329", "EMI_330", "EMI_331", "EMI_332", "EMI_333", 
>     "EMI_334", "EMI_335", "EMI_336", "EMI_337", "EMI_338", "EMI_339", 
>     "EMI_340", "EMI_341", "EMI_342", "EMI_343", "EMI_344", "EMI_345", 
>     "EMI_346", "EMI_347", "EMI_348", "EMI_349", "EMI_350", "EMI_351", 
>     "EMI_352", "EMI_353", "EMI_354", "EMI_355", "EMI_356", "EMI_357", 
>     "EMI_358", "EMI_359", "EMI_360", "EMI_361", "EMI_362", "EMI_363", 
>     "EMI_364", "EMI_365", "EMI_366", "EMI_367", "EMI_368", "EMI_369", 
>     "EMI_370", "EMI_371", "EMI_372", "EMI_373", "EMI_374", "EMI_375", 
>     "EMI_376", "EMI_377", "EMI_378", "EMI_379", "EMI_380", "EMI_381", 
>     "EMI_382", "EMI_383", "EMI_384", "EMI_385", "EMI_386", "EMI_388", 
>     "EMI_389", "EMI_390", "EMI_391", "EMI_392", "EMI_393", "EMI_394", 
>     "EMI_395", "EMI_396", "EMI_397", "EMI_398", "EMI_399", "EMI_400", 
>     "EMI_401", "EMI_402", "EMI_403", "EMI_404", "EMI_405", "EMI_406", 
>     "EMI_407", "EMI_408", "EMI_409", "EMI_410", "EMI_411", "EMI_412", 
>     "EMI_413", "EMI_414", "EMI_415", "EMI_416", "EMI_419", "EMI_420", 
>     "EMI_423", "EMI_424", "EMI_425", "EMI_426", "EMI_427", "EMI_428", 
>     "EMI_429", "EMI_430", "EMI_431", "EMI_432", "EMI_433", "EMI_434", 
>     "EMI_435", "EMI_436", "EMI_437", "EMI_438", "EMI_439", "EMI_440", 
>     "EMI_441", "EMI_442", "EMI_443", "EMI_444", "EMI_445", "EMI_446", 
>     "EMI_447", "EMI_448", "EMI_449", "EMI_450", "EMI_451", "EMI_452", 
>     "EMI_453", "EMI_454", "EMI_455", "EMI_456", "EMI_457", "EMI_458", 
>     "EMI_459", "EMI_460", "EMI_461", "EMI_462", "EMI_463", "EMI_464", 
>     "EMI_465", "EMI_466", "EMI_467", "EMI_468", "EMI_470", "EMI_471", 
>     "EMI_475", "EMI_476", "EMI_477", "EMI_478", "EMI_479", "EMI_480", 
>     "EMI_481", "EMI_482", "EMI_483", "EMI_484", "EMI_485", "EMI_486", 
>     "EMI_487", "EMI_491", "EMI_492", "EMI_493", "EMI_494", "EMI_495", 
>     "EMI_496", "EMI_497", "EMI_498", "EMI_499", "EMI_500", "EMI_501", 
>     "EMI_502", "EMI_503", "EMI_504", "EMI_505", "EMI_506", "EMI_507", 
>     "EMI_508", "EMI_509", "EMI_510", "EMI_511", "EMI_512", "EMI_513", 
>     "EMI_514", "EMI_515", "EMI_516", "EMI_517", "EMI_518"), class = "factor"), 
>     Twin_Number = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), visit = c("1", "2", "3", 
>     "4", "1", "2"), COMP_MEM_FU = c(0.089457934, -0.1278462, 
>     -0.08989273, -0.10930318, 0.384586641, 0.651491203), CRP_FU = c(1, 
>     NA, NA, NA, 1, NA), AGE_NEURO_FU = c(70.9, 73.1, 75.3, 77.7, 
>     70.9, 73.1), time_years_FU = c(0, 2.19999999999999, 4.39999999999999, 
>     6.8, 0, 2.19999999999999), CRP_Tertiles = c("Low", NA, NA, 
>     NA, "Low", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))
```